# Urge to open eyes

Tags: meditation

When I meditate after about 45 minutes I start to get this strong urge to finish and open my eyes. I use a timer and after a while I start to feel time dragging and wishing the bell would hurry up. I'm struggling to stay mindful when this happens as the feeling is so strong that it overwhelms and I end up finishing the sit. Any advise anyone can offer please?  Ive tried not using a timer which helps but that's difficult as I cannot just sit indefinitely most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the experience is that of the hindrance of restlessness.

You can try to 'note' or 'acknowledge' the experience, such as thinking: 'restlessness/tension' is now occurring.

Otherwise, you can break the meditation. To sit for 45 minutes is a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Ah K yes that sounds right. I'll try to note it. Thanks